# how does sigmoid activation implementation in tensorflow works?

Tags: tensorflow, sigmoid

I am running the following mnist implementation:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import LambdaCallback

# Load and preprocess the MNIST dataset
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()
train_images = train_images.reshape((60000, 28, 28, 1)).astype('float32') / 255
test_images = test_images.reshape((10000, 28, 28, 1)).astype('float32') / 255
train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels)
test_labels = to_categorical(test_labels)

# Build the neural network model
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))

# Add hidden layers with sigmoid activation
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='sigmoid'))

# Output layer with 10 units for 10 classes and softmax activation
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


# Define a callback to print the weighted sum of each neuron in the hidden layer during training
def log_hidden_layer_info(epoch, logs):
    hidden_layer_weights = model.layers[1].get_weights()[0]  # Weights of the first hidden layer
    hidden_layer_biases = model.layers[1].get_weights()[1]  # Biases of the first hidden layer
    hidden_layer_outputs = model.layers[1].output  # Adjust index based on the layer you want to inspect
    hidden_layer_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=hidden_layer_outputs)

    sample_image = train_images[0:1]
    activations = hidden_layer_model.predict(sample_image)

    for i in range(hidden_layer_weights.shape[1]):
        weighted_sum = (activations * hidden_layer_weights[:, i:i + 1]).sum() + hidden_layer_biases[i]
        print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1}, Neuron {i + 1} - Weighted Sum: {weighted_sum}, Activation: {activations[0][i]}')


log_callback = LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=log_hidden_layer_info)

# Train the model with the callback
model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10, batch_size=64, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[log_callback])

# Evaluate the model on the test set
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)
print(f'Test accuracy: {test_acc}')
```

As you can see I print both weighted sum for a hidden layer and the activation result (which I assume is sigmoid operates on the weighted sum)

I get the following output:

```
... 
Epoch 10, Neuron 14 - Weighted Sum: 4576.98388671875, Activation: 0.9452044367790222 
Epoch 10, Neuron 15 - Weighted Sum: 275.4674072265625, Activation: 0.9996762871742249 
Epoch 10, Neuron 16 - Weighted Sum: -789.8799438476562, Activation: 0.04697105288505554
Epoch 10, Neuron 17 - Weighted Sum: -2768.070556640625, Activation: 0.11655014753341675 
Epoch 10, Neuron 18 - Weighted Sum: 1269.995849609375, Activation: 0.7969928979873657 
Epoch 10, Neuron 19 - Weighted Sum: -1751.06103515625, Activation: 0.8819616436958313 
Epoch 10, Neuron 20 - Weighted Sum: -3794.892578125, Activation: 0.0007617903756909072 
...
```

I can't figure out the results because sigmoid(-3794.892578125) is almost 0, but sigmoid(-1751.06103515625) should also be almost 0.
Also, sigmoid(275.4674072265625) should be close to 1 (0.9996762871742249 above), but sigmoid(1269.995849609375) is 0.7969928979873657, and sigmoid(4576.98388671875) is 0.9452044367790222, how come?

Can anyone explain how does it work?